# find elements from an array such that no two are adjacent and whose sum is maximum

Tags: algorithm

Find a sequence containing elements of given array such that no two elements are adjacent and we are required to maximise the sum of the sequence formed.

input :- { 4 , 1 , 3 , 4 }

output :- 4 4

Comment: any particular language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a python code

```python
a = [4, 1, 3, 4]
bestSeq = []
seq = []

def solve(i):
    global maxSum, bestSeq
    if i >= len(a):
        if sum(seq) > sum(bestSeq):
            # Copy Current sequence into best sequence if sum is greater than maxSum
            bestSeq = seq[:]
    else:
        # Include the current element and go to i +2
        seq.append(a[i])
        solve(i + 2)
        seq.pop()

        # Skip the current element and go to i+1
        solve(i + 1)


solve(0)
print(bestSeq)
```

You have to either choose the current array element and go to i+2 (cause next index will be adjacent to this one) or you can skip add the current element and go to i+1. Do this recursively at every index in the array.

If the index is greater than n then stop and compare the current seq with the already bestSeq, if the sum is greater then save the current sequence.

### Optimization Using Dynamic Programming

```python
import time
import random
random.seed(19950406)

a = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(40)]
DP = [[] for i in a]  # This will hold bestSeq from i, initially empty
seq = []

def solveDP(i):
    global DP

    if i >= len(a):
        return []

    # If this value is already computed return that value
    if len(DP[i]) > 0:
        return DP[i]

    # Include the current element and go to i +2
    arr1 = [a[i]] + solveDP(i + 2)
    # Skip the current element and go to i+1
    arr2 = solveDP(i + 1)
    if sum(arr1) > sum(arr2):
        DP[i] = arr1[:]    # Copy arr1 into DP[i]
    else:
        DP[i] = arr2[:]    # Copy arr2 into DP[i]
    return DP[i]

# Main
start = time.time()
print(solveDP(0))
print("Time Taken : {:.6f}".format(time.time() - start))
```

### Output

```
[88, 26, 100, 63, 31, 98, 61, 15, 76, 31, 69, 72, 81, 29, 61, 84, 44, 81]
Time Taken : 0.000000
```

As you can see the dynamic programming version is much faster than the traditional recursive solution. But memory will be really large for really large values of n (10^6 and beyond)

Comment: Tts nice solution but can we reduce the time complexity of the program ? can we do it more efficiently

Comment: Yes I think if you just wanted the sum you could use Dynamic Programming to store the computed value for a given index.

Comment: No,  I want elements which will contribute to the sum

Comment: You could still use dynamic programming and store the best sequence from `i` but the memory requirements might be quite high for large arrays

Comment: Okay,  I can sacrifice with memory,  can you tell me how to do it by the method that you are telling,  I am not able to get how to do it what you are saying in your last comment.

Comment: Updated question with DP solution

Comment: Can we do it iterative rather than recursive because in the case of recursive it might overload the stack. // your Optimised solution is very helpful and thanks for all this .

Comment: I don't think you should worry about stack calls, their memory requirements  are tiny compared to the DP array. Im glad I could help :)

Comment: if we write the same optimised solution in C++ than what would be the best data structure for this , a list or vector ?

Comment: A vector definitely.

Comment: Okay , but can we make it more optimised as in every recursive call we are returning a list , and thus we are copying it and it will take linear time  , Can we use other data structure that won't required that kind of copying everytime.

Comment: your solution is based on memoization but  can we use dynamic programming